# Sharing two image and two text in UIActivityViewController is not working properlly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller

Sharing **two image** and **two text** in `UIActivityViewController` is not working properlly.

**Following is my code.**

```
NSString *title1 = @"up thumbs";
NSString *title2 = @"down thumbs";
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up-thumbs"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down-thumbs"];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[title1, image1, title2, image2] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Share in **email** it display as following **but my need** is display **first title1** then **image1** then **title2** then **image2**.

[image]

Share in **notes** it display as following. It **display only title1 not display title2** and **both image is same space**.

How display **both title** and **both image** separate.

[image]

how to solve this problem.

Please help me!